# how to get the model's max x,y,z withing loading model by assimp

Tags: model, max, width, min, assimp

I want to split model space with octree to check intersection detection,
so i need known model's max x,y,z and min xyz.

to get the result,i traverse all meshes's vertex and compare them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a post-processing step for that. You can use it in the following way:

```
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>

::Assimp::Importer importer;
auto scene = importer.import("testmodel.obj", aiProcess_GenBoundingBoxes);
const aabb &aabb = scene->mMeshes[0]->mAABB;
```

At first you have to enable the flag when you are starting the import. Then the post-processing will iterate through all imported meshes and fill the bounding boxes.

And here is a simple unittest for the feature: [Bounding boxes unittest](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/test/unit/utGenBoundingBoxesProcess.cpp)

Comment: could you tell how to use it?     

I have got aiScene,I don't know how to use it .sorry ,i'm not familiar with c++.Thank you very mush.
 Assimp::Importer importer;
        const aiScene *scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_GenSmoothNormals | aiProcess_FlipUVs | aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace);

Comment: Hope that helps.

Comment: that's what i want ,thank you very mush